# Two switch breaker reads hot with Main power off

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

[image]Reformatted question:

I have, with this same set up, and the question to still be asked, successfully (loosely termed) replaced a 2 prong 20 Amp breaker, and another seperate 2 prong 20 Amp breaker, while this current issue/question was as it is now, only now, one of the two switches on the breaker is not springing either direction. It is a 2 prong (switch) 15 Amp. So, what I am confused by, is, when I swapped out the other two breakers, this one breaker, with two switches, has always had power read hot even after I turned off the main, and unplugged everything in the home, and made sure there was a connected ground, going into the ground. But, since this breaker not working on one switch, affects the whole left side of the house, I have no power in the bed, bath, and dining room, only the kitchen, and living room. Where I got to this site and asking a question, is, that when I have power off and all breakers off, it reads hot on the loose switch, but when I turn the main power back on , and the breakers ON,it reads no power.. Here we go.. And lastly, when the main power is ON, and the SAME breakers bottom switch is ON, it reads NO POWER.. SO, I HAVE to do this work myself, I am careful and aware and afraid to die, but confident to listen to reason and understand what is explained, and able to execute guidance perfectly.. What I want to know is, 2 things:

can I switch the stuff how I said things are switched & it reads NO power, and remove that one line?,.. (Then switch things how they normally go, to deaden the other switch, and remove the whole breaker) only to do the same backwards to get the new breaker in, however this person has this thing, just so I can have the power back on in the rest of the house?
Or..

Can I take my Klien insulated electricians screwdriver, insulated gloves, and Milwaukee insulated stripper, and be safe to go about this another way to get that breaker out and put a new one in, until I can afford to have a pro come out and redo the entire box?

Comment: Can you post photos of the breaker panel in question please?

Comment: Sure- I'm new here. Let me locate where I post pics

Comment: @borogoat Click "edit" under your question and then click the 6th icon from the left to insert a photo.

Comment: I uploaded two u already had taken before finding the site, I'm going to get a better set of pictures, the red 20's showing I already did, but that blue 15 at the top with the open top switch is reading hot always..and that's the one I want to change

Comment: Beyond the advice to replace the whole panel _last week!_, your question is still very unclear. "can I switch the stuff how I said things are switched & it reads NO power, and remove that one line?" Sure? Maybe? Who know? that just doesn't make sense? "That stuff" is hard for us to follow. Pictures, clearly labeled diagrams, referring to those labels - those are all things that are necessary for us to follow you. TBH, though, the best bet is going to be to get an electrician in to replace the panel and clean up any other messes he finds.

Comment: Panel will be fully replaced . The question was IS IT possible to change out a breaker if ut still is hot..please read updated question  I thank you for your persistent need for a clearer explanation and will always try to make it extremely concise  it's just that this issue was a conundrum not being a pro and not having the little quirks known...thank you agsin and  heck out thr beginning of the edit question

Comment: @borogoat -- please don't clobber what you already have in your post when you're adding conclusions :) (I rolled back the culprit edit for you)

Answer (score 5):

### No wonder you're having trouble

Your confusion is most understandable as breakers are indeed *not* supposed to misbehave like this, but since your panel is a Zinsco with its attendant [troubled history](https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Zinsco_Summary.htm), its no wonder you're having issues.  You'll need to have the panel changed out wholesale for something of a modern, safe, and reliable design.

Comment: Minor point for anyone whose native language is not English:  in this context, "wholesale" means "completely ".

Comment: If I understand the problems with those panels, yesterday is already leaving it late.

Comment: @crip659 yeah, the Zinsco issues are *not* pretty

Comment: The _issues_ aren't pretty, but all those color-coded breaker handles sure are!